# What is the difference between self.button.layer.backgroundColor and self.button.backgroundColor?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a functional difference between these two lines of Swift code ?

```
self.button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

and

```
self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

?

Comment: http://raptureinvenice.com/ios-brownbag-view-vs-layers-including-clock-demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [John Blanco's blog](http://raptureinvenice.com/ios-brownbag-view-vs-layers-including-clock-demo/):

> Every UIView comes packaged with a CALayer knows as the “backing
>   layer” or “underlying layer.” Many of the methods you call on UIView
>   simply delegate to the layer. When you change a view’s frame, it’s
>   simply changing the layer’s frame. If you change the alpha, it changes
>   the layer’s alpha…and so on with background colors, transformations
>   and more. And while you can maintain a hierarchy of UIViews each
>   representing parents and children of one another, you can do the same
>   with CALayer

Comment: Thanks.  So really, the self.button.backgroundColor function is just delegating to the equivalent function (self.button.layer.backgroundColor) for the CALayer.

Comment: No problem. That's my understanding, unless someone has evidence to the contrary.